# What is "sustained investment"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is a quotation from a text about the Internet:

> The Internet represents one of the most successful examples of the
>   benefits of **sustained investment** and commitment to research and
>   development of information infrastructure.

What does "sustained investment" mean in current context?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Sustained** is being used in its sense of "prolonged" or "maintained for a long time without a break". "Sustain" comes from Latin *[teneō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/teneo),* meaning "I hold", plus the prefix [*sub*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sub#Preposition_5) meaning "underneath" or "pushing up from below"—in other words, "I hold (something) up." In English, the word still conveys a feeling of expending effort or energy to keep something going. For example, to "sustain" a musical note means to hold it for a long duration.

So, in your example sentence, **sustained investment** means continued investment for many years. "Sustained" is a nicer word choice than "continued", though, because of that suggestion of deliberate effort in addition to continuing without a break for a long time.

---

By the way, this illustrates why the etymology in a dictionary definition is often worthwhile to read. It often sheds light on the "core" meaning of a word, which has spread into a few related or specialized meanings over the centuries.

Comment: Sorry if this should be written elsewhere, but I hope that user 'Ben Kovitz' sees this. I just wanted to emphasise and thank you for including your afterwords on the bigger issues or pictures behind each question (such as your last para above and last two paras [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/48714/8712)). They (supernally) benefit towards helping us learn and see the 'grand design' ourselves! Once again, thank you!